Github audit logs showing organization name as github actor
While going through the audit logs of github enterprise organization, I found out a lot of audit logs depicting github actor name as the name of the organization instead of an actual person name:
@timestamp  2024-05-22 11:40:09
action  repo.add_member
actor   My-Org-acme
actor_id    60
business    acme

Why doesn't it show the name of a user ? Is there a way to avoid this ?
